# Loops and string output

Tags: c#, string, loops

Hi i have the following code:

```
static void CalcWordchange()
{
    List<string[]> l = new List<string[]>
        {
        new string[]{Question1, matcheditalian1},
        new string[]{"Sam", matcheditalian2},
        new string[]{"clozapine", matcheditalian3},
        new string[]{"flomax", matcheditalian4},
        new string[]{"toradol", matcheditalian5},
        };

    foreach (string[] a in l)
    {
        int cost = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(a[0], a[1]);
        errorString = String.Format("To change your input: \n {0} \n into the correct word: \n {1} \n you need to make: \n {2} changes \n ".Replace("\n",      Environment.NewLine),
            a[0],
            a[1],
            cost);
    }
}
```

Each time a button is clicked the text in the foreach loop runs and outputs a single sentence (the last item in the list).  What i want to happen is to output all 5 items into a string.

I have added 4 new variables (errorString2, 3 etc) but cannot work out how to output it.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `StringBuilder` object to collect all the parts.

```
StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string[] a in l)
{
    int cost = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(a[0], a[1]);
    buildString.AppendFormat("To change your input: \n {0} \n into the correct word: \n {1} \n you need to make: \n {2} changes \n ".Replace("\n",      Environment.NewLine),
        a[0],
        a[1],
        cost);
}
errorString = buildString.ToString();
```

Comment: How does `buildString.AppendLine` differ from `string +=` ?  I'm assuming it is a better optimization in speed vs. the concatenation you referenced in my post?

Comment: @wjhguitarman: Yes.  The string concatenation creates and throws away a bunch of temporary strings.  `StringBuilder` preallocates a buffer and writes several items into it, then extends the buffer if it runs out.  So both faster and uses less memory.

Comment: @wjhguitarman: String Concatenation creates a new string each time it is used (i.e. each pass through the loop), where as StringBuilder uses a self-growing char[] behind the scenes (until you call .ToString()).  If that runs out of room, then StringBuilder will create a new array that is double the size of the old array.  This means that it will take longer and longer for the array to need to be re-created, rather than one new string object every pass of the loop.  String Concatination is still good for non-loops, especially if you are just adding 2-4 strings together.

Answer (score 2):

Instead do something like this:

```
 string finalOuput = string.empty;
 foreach (string[] a in l)
 {
  int cost = levelshteinDstance.Compute(a[0], a[1]);
  finalOutput += string.Format("To change your input: \n {0} \n into the correct word: \n {1} \n you need to make: \n {2} changes \n ".Replace("\n",      Environment.NewLine),
            a[0],
            a[1],
            cost);
    }
}
```

//display finalOutput here

Comment: Please don't recommend string concatentation in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `List<string>` to hold the output:

```
var OutputList = new List<string>();
foreach (string[] a in l)
{
    errorString = ...
    OutputList.Add(errorString);
}

// output
foreach (var s in OutputList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Or you could use a `StringBuilder`:

```
var outputS = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string[] a in l)
{
    errorstring = ...
    outputS.AppendLine(errorString);
}

Console.WriteLine(outputS.ToString());
```